# Complex integral with roots

Tags: complex-analysis, complex-numbers, contour-integration, complex-integration, cauchy-integral-formula

Integral on $C$ of $\int g(z)\,\mathrm dz$

$C$ is:

[image]

(those points are $1$ and $e$)

$$\begin{align}
g(z) &= z^{1/4}\\
g(1) &= i\\
\end{align}$$

How do I evaluate this using Anti-derivative method?

Comment: As the function is analytic in a domain that includes this curve (the border of the domain includes 1,so you can use$ \int_{a}^{b}f(x)dx=F(b)-F(a)$ here $F(z)=\frac{1}{4} z ^ \frac{-3}{4}$ and in $z=1$ you must put the limit of $g(z)$ as$ z$ leads to 1 that is 1.

Comment: F(z) is the integral because F'(z)=f(z). I don't think what you said works.

Comment: This is a theory about analytic functions!and something else:I must have written $F(z)=4 z ^ \frac {-3}{4} $ according to  mentioned theory it must work!